# SQL Join query in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatasource

I am not really sure about how to do this.

In a table `Product1` I have:

```
Id, Code, Description, Group, Quantity, Unit, Cost, Note
```

In the other table `Componets` I have:

```
Id, Code, Description, Unit, Cost, Note
```

The problem I am facing is that while table `Components` has always all columns with data, table `Product1` should take the data relevant "Description, Unit and Cost" from table "Components". In this table "Product1" basically only the Code, Quantity, Group and Note are added by the user.

Is this possible to achieve this with a query made in a `SqlDataSource`? I have no idea on how to do this and I would appreciate your help.

So far this is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
   Product1.Code, Group, Quantity, Product1.Note
FROM
   dbo.Product1
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Components ON Components.Code = Product1.Code
```

But I do not get what I need, I get only `Code`, `Group`, `Quantity` and `Note` from `Product1` table

Comment: You need to give the table alias, or fully specify the table name when you are selecting columns that appear in both tables.

Comment: Your most recent edit to the question has completely changed your original issue.

Comment: @NicholasV. yes, sorry you are right but meanwhile I am trying to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets understand why they are 'ambiguous'.

Because your join is on two tables both having the same column names. Since, you have not specified the table name for those columns, the SQL engine is confused which table you want those columns from? Hence, it says ambiguous. Just use an alias as such:

`GENERAL IDEA`:

```
SELECT tab.id, tab.Name

FROM TableName tab
```

WHERE tab is called the alias.

With respect to you question, this the query you need:

```
SELECT         prod.Code,
               prod.Groupp,
               prod.Quantity,
               prod.Note,
               comp.Description,
               comp.Unit,
               comp.Cost

FROM           dbo.Product1 prod    
INNER JOIN     dbo.Components comp
ON             comp.Code = prod.Code
//Any Where conditions should follow here
```

Observe how `prod` and `comp` are used as the aliases. They will not cause you any 'ambiguity'.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks, I am startinh to get a picture of what is about. The query is giving me errors. I have all the columns in Select with red underline

Comment: have you tried running the query? Sometimes, SQL Server gives "red lines" for fun. So try running the query :)

Comment: Yes I did it again and now only this line gives error:  com.Unit, impossible to associate the identifier in more parts

Comment: Oops!!!My bad..Thats a spelling mistake. It should be comp.Unit and not com.Unit. Edited my answer. Check that!! Guess this will work!!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!! :)

Comment: Just FYI - @sockfd's answer was first, and correctly addresses the issue just as well...

Answer (score 3):

It means your fields (columns) Code and Note appear in both tables; thus one should use a table prefix, which points out from which table one will fetch the column:

```
SELECT Components.Code AS 'Components Code', Product1.Code AS 'Product Code', Groupp, Quantity, Components.Note AS 'Components Node', Product1.Note AS 'Product Note'

FROM
dbo.Product1

INNER JOIN dbo.Components
ON Components.Code = Product1.Code
```

As demonstrated above, one can include multiple columns and give them a label when fetched.

Comment: Meanwhile I have updated my question too. But in this way I get only part of the data.

Comment: This is nearlygiving me what I need. Thank you a lot for your help. I will try to work out my need from here.